# jQuery change textfield in tablerow by dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I'm not very firm with JS and this whole jQuery thing.

This is my actuall HTML Output created in a foreach-loop:

```js
$('#ProjectOfferPosition0IsystemTypeVariantId').on('change', function () {
    var prices = [];
    prices[1] = 500.00;
    prices[2] = 600.00;
    prices[6] = 1000.00
    var key = $('#ProjectOfferPosition0IsystemTypeVariantId option:selected').val();
    var oldPrice = 800.00;
    $('#ProjectOfferPosition0Price').val(prices[parseInt(key,10)] + oldPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="data[ProjectOfferPosition][0][isystem_id]" value="1" id="ProjectOfferPosition0IsystemId"/><input type="hidden" name="data[ProjectOfferPosition][0][count]" value="1" id="ProjectOfferPosition0Count"/>I</td>
  <td><select name="data[ProjectOfferPosition][0][isystem_type_variant_id]" id="ProjectOfferPosition0IsystemTypeVariantId" class="select" required="required">
    <option value="">ohne Variante wählen</option>
    <option value="1">INPUT Basis System Wohnung 60</option>
    <option value="2">INPUT System Wohnung 100</option>
    <option value="6">INPUT System Haus 300</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><input name="data[ProjectOfferPosition][0][price]" step="0.01" type="number" value="800.00" id="ProjectOfferPosition0Price" class="input"/><input type="hidden" name="data[ProjectOfferPosition][0][position]" value="1" id="ProjectOfferPosition0Position"/></td>
</tr>
```

when i change the value of the dropdown i want the textfield in the same row updated (add a option-price to the existing product).
thing is tho, i don't know how to 'read' which row i'm in (the [0]-Part)

**EDIT**
got it running. still but still hardcoded, not dynamical responding to multiple rows

thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Remove "if you need more specific information i'm online the whole day" line .. and post what have you done till now ..

Comment: Do you have value / text pair on your select or only text items?

Comment: Instead of pseudocode, post actual code (having 3 or 4 Select Options) and then write what is your expected output...

Comment: updated the post - added actual code and current solution by Simon Mason

Answer (score 0):

Giving your select an id as well that corresponds with the text field such as for example "select-id-nr" and "text-id-nr". You can then check for the select field on change, and simply take it's value and apply it to the text field with the same number id. You can take the corresponding id you need out of the event target's id which you'll get in the on change event object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the change, grab the selected text and then add this to the required td.

```
$('.js-my-select').on('change', function(){
  var text = $('.js-my-select option:selected').text();
  $('.js-selected').val(text);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8r4nL5s/

Comment: thx, i updated my original post and added your solution. but i'm still struggling making it dynamic (the [0]-Part of the id)

Comment: When you say it is still hard coded, do you mean you are coding the html rather than generating it with your php script? You mentioned using a foreach loop to generate the table - is this working? Perhaps you could share the php code as well, then I might be able to provide a more complete solution.